# 'IConfigurationSection' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no accessible extension

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, jwt, n-tier-architecture

I created the JwtHelper class. I have been using it for a long time. However, when I updated the packages, I got an error in the following line;

[image: Error Lines]

The complete error message is as follows;

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS1061  'IConfigurationSection' does not contain a definition for
> 'Get' and no accessible extension method 'Get' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IConfigurationSection' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**I found the solution. I'm writing here so you don't waste time.**

Answer (score 33):

***Go to Nuget and download the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" package.***

[image]

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder -Version 5.0.0
```